# Checkbox Validation to Check atleast One Checkbox is selected

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have created one intractive report with checkbox, here in report if i have not selected any checkbox then it should through errorlike "select atleast one checkbox" in oracle apex

Kindly assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an interactive report on table emp with this as query:

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO,
       APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,empno) checkbox
  from EMP
```

Add a button to the with action "Submit Page"

Create a validation of type "Function Body (returning Boolean)" with source code

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP
    RETURN true;
  END LOOP;  
  RETURN false;
END;
```

and error message "At least one checkbox must be checked"

That is all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a validation of a "PL/SQL function which returns error text" type.

```
begin
if  apex_application.g_f01 is not null and 
    apex_application.g_f01.count > 0 
then
   return 'select atleast one checkbox!!';
end if;
return null;
end;
```